# C# With Devexpress Framework

Tags: c#, devexpress

[error uccur when I opening the forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRX3W.png)

Hi, I was working on project using C#  with devExpress framework ,and the project was running without problem, but when I reinstall windows 10, visual studio and devexpress, I faced problem when I open the project.
if someone know what the solution, please help me!

Comment: We need more details. What's the problem?

Comment: Check your References see if there is two different versions of Devexpress